# How many hours would you reccomend to master one Intermediate Classical piece for Level 5 RCM exam?

Tags: piano, practice, performing

How many hours in total would you recommend for an average student, from beginning to examination, to prepare a typical Level 5 ( out of 10 ) Royal Conservatory of Music List B Classical Repertoire selection ? For example : Sonatina in F major,Anh.5,no.2 First Movement by Ludwig van Beethoven. Or Mozart's Viennese Sonatina in C major (no.1) 2nd Movement : Minuetto and Trio ?

Comment: I reckon it would take just as long as a piece of string.

Comment: This is an impossible question to answer wwith any help at all. We might know about music, but we don't know you or your capabilities. Vtc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It mainly depends on how old the player is, the skill level, and how long they have played the instrument. It really depends but I would say 1 month maybe.

Comment: 30 days x 2 hours per day = 60 hours total , or 60 days x 1 hour per day ; would probably work for me.

Comment: Is there a typical age range for this level?